# Warning message when installing devtools

Tags: rstudio, r-devtools

When I try to install devtools in Rstudio 3.2.3 (Windows 10) using the command install.packages("devtools"), I get the following message:

warning in install.packages :

```
'lib = "c:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.3//library"' is not writable
```

I'm a newby and I've been hunting for solutions but so far am coming up empty. I would appreciate any advice that might get me through this step. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you have no privileges to wirte in the "Programm Files" directory

Comment: After trying several things such as "run as administrator for Rstudio" and going to the tools-global options-packages and unclicking Use Internet Explorer/Library for HTTP (based on a suggestion from another site), I was finally able to install devtools, but now I can't get it to load. The only thing that happens is that I get a new >. Here's a screen shot.
> find.package("devtools")
[1] "C:/Users/Julia/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/devtools"
> library(devtools)
> library(devtools)
> library (devtools)
>

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same issue earlier. This "problem" arises when you try to install a library for the first time and R does not have a a dedicated library for it yet.

Two pop-up should appear one after the other when you try to install a package like:

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
```

The questions are the following:

- Would you like to use a personal library instead?
- Would you like to create a personal library 'C:\Users\bartlein\Documents/R/win-library/3.2' to install packages into?

Answer yes to both questions and you should be fine.

The ressources I used came from [here](http://geog.uoregon.edu/bartlein/courses/geog495/exercises/packages-and-data.html).

Comment: Do not hesitate to validate the answer if it is correct ;)